# ML Kit Deploy to Device Without Play Services

Tags: service, playback

We have a kiosk type Android device that is very stripped down and doesn't have the Play Store or Play Services installed.  We would like to utilize OCR and some of the other services provided by ML Kit but w/o Play Services installed, it's throwing an error that Play Services are missing.   The app works fine on standard Android phones that do have the Play Store and Services.  Question:  is it possible to install the ML Kit dependencies via the packaging of the app that it normally needs from Play Services?  Or is there a safe way to install Play Services from apk?